# nova volume-detach fails silently, compute log shows libvirtError: invalid argument: no target device vdb

Tags: iscsi, libvirt, openstack, virsh, openstack-nova

Using Openstack Havana, I'm trying to detach a cinder volume from a nova instance.

Nova volume-list shows it as in-use:

```
| 34b0ea26-f85c-4b62-8ebd-884b0e63e2d5 | in-use | filestore | 256  | None| 4d05ffe4-d30a-4c93-b710-c9ec80dad1c2 |
```

The volume is connected via iscsi:

```
# iscsiadm -m session
tcp: [5] 10.3.40.10:3260,1 iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-34b0ea26-f85c-4b62-8ebd-884b0e63e2d5 (non-flash)
```

It's visible as /dev/vdb within the instance, and is mountable and read/writable.

However, after unmounting it in the instance and issuing

```
# nova volume-detach 4d05ffe4-d30a-4c93-b710-c9ec80dad1c2 34b0ea26-f85c-4b62-8ebd-884b0e63e2d5
```

it does not detach. The volume stays labeled "in-use". I get this error in the compute.log:

```
libvirtError: invalid argument: no target device vdb
```

When I run "virsh edit 4" on the compute node, the disk device for vdb is in fact missing. However, when I run "virsh dumpxml 4" it is still there!

How can I untangle this?

Virsh dumpxml vs. edit diff:
http://pastebin.com/3CrGbcwu

Compute.log of the error:
http://pastebin.com/1UCahB3d

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the libvirt configuration resynchronized by copying the  XML from the xml dump into its own file, and then updated it back into the current configuration via

```
virsh attach-device 4 filestore.xml --config
```

After that, I reran nova volume-detach. It succeeded in cleaning up the compute node, the iscsi session is now idle. However, now the volume was stuck in "detaching" status. No errors anywhere, no idea why it didn't go back to "available." tgt-admin allowed me to take it offline and back to ready, then I got it back to available status with cinder reset-state.